# How to use grid system inside <nav> tag?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement `grid system` with `row` and `col` using **bootstrap 4.0**, but I'm facing issue.

If I use the `<div>` tag, so far it's working fine:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-2 text-left">
 left
 </div>
 <div class="col-8 text-center">
 main title
 </div>
 <div class="col-2 text-right">
 right
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I try to implement the above logic in the `nav` tag by entering the toggler button. But it's looks messy (not symmetric):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark text-white">
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-2 text-left">
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="menu-toggle">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-8 text-center">
 main title
 </div>
 <div class="col-2 text-right">
        right
 </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Give w-100 to row of div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display: block` to your nav

```
nav{
display:block;
}
```

Because navbar class change the display to flex .

```
<nav class="d-block">
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the below code:

```js
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark text-white">
    <div class="row w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-2 text-left">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="menu-toggle">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 text-center">
            main title
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-right">
            right
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark text-white row">
   
 <div class="col-2 text-left">
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="menu-toggle">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-8 text-center">
 main title
 </div>
 <div class="col-2 text-right">
        right
 </div>
    
</nav>
```

Comment: add `row` class from `nav` tag